# What is a good way to monitor the uptime of an Elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, monitoring

I have a 10 node Elasticsearch cluster, and I would like to know the uptime of the cluster.
I used the [cluster stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-stats.html) and saw a parameter,named "max_uptime" under the jvm object. 
[image]

Our team observed the cluster for one week and there was no downtime for one week. But the jvm.max_uptime parameter returns only 72 hours. So what does this parameter tells us?.
Also, what would be a good idea to monitor the uptime of an Elasticsearch Cluster?.

Comment: You can use Kibana Monitoring: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/elasticsearch-metrics.html

Comment: @Val
any idea what the jvm.max_uptime parameter tells us?

Comment: It's the duration since the JVM last started up.